# vb.net char literal for integer

Tags: vb.net, char, literals, chr

Using the commandline visual basic compiler (vbc.exe) with option VBruntime-
does not allow using chr() or chrw() to specify a literal char.
MSDN gives "x"c as solution to specify a literal character.
That works fine, but how can i specify a literal character for a integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [System.Convert.ToChar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hkfdkcx.aspx#Y0) to convert an integer to a character value.  That is defined in mscorlib so it will be available no matter what your command line options.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you. Now i want to have a one char string from a constant integer. I can do it as follows : Dim Lc as Char = Convert.ToChar(&H09):Dim Lca(0) as Char:Lca(0)=Lc:Dim Ls$=New string(Lca) . Do you know a shorter syntax?

Comment: Use the String construtor that takes a `Char` and a count: `Dim Ls$=New string(Convert.ToChar(&H09), 1)` - Please my answer as accepted by checking the checkmark.